# Rename a Xcode Project to a new app

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have a Xcode8 project with swift3 been released as version 1.0. Then I enhanced the project to version 2.0. But now customer requires to have both these two apps (i.e v1.0 and v2.0) existing on the iPhone at the same time.

I have tried to rename the v2.0 project names, but whenever I install the 2nd project, it overwrites the existing project.

Any suggestion on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, I need to rename the bundle identifier in the project General settings to make it a new app.